# PDO Query Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, pdo, fetch

I have been trying to pull all infomation where $user is equal to subscriberID in my sql database. I am using the PDO method of inserting data and wish to use the query function also.
i am getting the following error message back from my try condition.

Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object

I have considered maybe the problem has been caused by the method i use to pull the data as im fairly new to PDO.(i include a top.php that establishes the link to the database)

Thank you for your suggestions

```
 <?php
 include "top.php";

    try{
        $user = $_SESSION['login'];
        echo "Welcome <strong>$user</strong> to your saved holidays";

        //$getSavedHolidays = $db->query("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID='$user'");
        //preparing a PDO statment for accessing saved holidays when the logged in user matchs the subscriberID
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $getSavedHolidays = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID=:user");
        //uses a bind valu as this makes the statment more secure
        $getSavedHolidays->bindValue(":user", $_SESSION['login']);
        $getsavedHolidays->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $getSavedHolidays->execute();


        foreach ($Result as $row)
            {
                echo "<p><a href'".$row['link']."'>".$row['title']."</a><br \>" . 
                     $row['description'] . "<br \>" . 
                     $row['pubDate'] ."<br \></p>";
            }

        }

        catch (PDOException $e) 
            {
                 print_r($e->errorInfo);
                    die();
            }
```

?>

Comment: You have an error: `$$getSavedHolidays = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID=:user");` should be `$getSavedHolidays` (and not `$$`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be preparing your statement. It has a nice added bonus of being more secure, plus it will solve your problem.

```
$user = $_SESSION['login'];

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $getSavedHolidays = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID=:user");
    $getSavedHolidays->bindValue(":user", $_SESSION['login']);
    $getSavedHolidays->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $getSavedHolidays->execute();
    $Result = $getSavedHolidays->fetchAll();

    foreach ($Result as $row) {/*...*/}

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print_r($e->errorInfo);
    die();
}
```

### EDIT

You have an error in the code you've pasted above:

```
$$getSavedHolidays = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID=:user");
```

Should be

```
$getSavedHolidays = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID=:user");
```

Comment: It escapes it perfectly to prevent SQL Injection (among other things).

Comment: I have an issue with the bind sorry. Fatal error: Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object.

Comment: Let me place a full code, it will allow you to debug as well.

Comment: @HxMGraeme: I've pasted a full code, it will make PDO throw a `PDOException` on error, which is catchable using a `try catch` block.

Comment: thats great thanks but im still getting the error Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object. Is this due to my fetch method?

Answer (score 2):

there is explicit syntax error. mussing closing single quote:

```
$getSavedHolidays = $db->query("SELECT * FROM saved_holidays WHERE subscriberID='$user'");
```

and by the way, since you're using PDO it's more safe to use [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) function to pass values to SQL request.

Comment: thanks i cant believe i missed it i was looking over it for a good half hour. Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object is the new error is this due to my fetch method